# Html timeout workaround required

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

We have designed a html page which should timeout after 10 minutes of inactivity.
This logic is implemented as

```
function CheckExpire()
{
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:self.location.pathname+"?checkexpire",
        data:'',
        dataType:"json"
    })
    .done(function(exp){
        if(exp.expired != "no")
            window.location.reload();
    })
}

setInterval( function() {

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:window.location.href+"wan_config_ipv6.cgi?status",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function(data,status){  }

},2000);

    LoadTopMenu();
    $("#div_menu_left ul li").eq(0).click();
    setInterval("CheckExpire();", 10000);
 })
```

However, later we need to update a status every 2 sec from the same function.
After the change the web does not get logout after 10 minutes of inactivity, because every 2 sec the webpage is active.

Could any one suggest workaround for this issue or implement alternative method for logout along with status update.

server side cgi code

```
int CGIMain(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    head("Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    head("Cache-Control:private,max-age=0;");


    if(argc==2&&!strcmp(argv[1],"checkexpire"))
    {
        check_expire(); //exported a JSON object and exit
        return 0;
    }

static void check_expire()
{
    struct session_data sdata;
    char *sid = CGIGetCookie("sid");
    int expired = 2;
    unsigned expinsec = 0;

    memset(&sdata, 0, sizeof(sdata));
    if(sid && load_session_data(&sdata)==0)
    {
        if(!strcmp(sdata.sid,sid))
        {
            struct sysinfo si;
            sysinfo(&si);
            expired = (sdata.expire < si.uptime);
            expinsec = sdata.expire - si.uptime;
        }
    }
    char* estat[] = {"no", "yes", "unknown"};
    vwrite("{\"expired\":\"%s\", \"expire\":\"%d\"}", estat[expired],
           expinsec);

    return -1;
}


char* CGIGetCookie(char *name)
{
    char *co_str=getenv("HTTP_COOKIE");
    if(co_str)
    {
        return GetCookieVal(name,strdup(co_str));
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Who/what is keeping track of the 10 minutes of inactivity?  Server-side code?  Or browser-side?  If it's the server keeping track of inactivity, then you will either have to change the server code to ignore this particular ajax call as a measure of activity or you will have to have the client specifically log out itself.  If it's the client keeping track of inactivity, then you just need to update that logic to not count this ajax request as activity.  It seems the operative code is the code that keeps track of activity.

Comment: user side browser code

Comment: @jfriend00: How to do such a thing?
 If it's the client keeping track of inactivity, then you just "need to update that logic to not count this ajax request as activity".

Comment: If you show us exactly what code is keeping track of your definition of "activity", then and only then can we help you modify that code.  Right now, your code looks like it's asking the server if things have expired so it appears the server is keeping track of the activity timer.

Comment: we are using thttpd-2.25 as the web server in the box.

Comment: Where's the server-side code that implements the checkexpire ajax call?

Comment: updated in the above section

Comment: What server-side code sets `sdata.expire` in the session data?  Is that modified on every server request?  Still an incomplete description of how your inactivity timer actually works.

Comment: @jfriend00: updated complete session expire flow code

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable that would increment every time you make AJAX call and when it reaches 5, logout.

Comment: It does not sound like this meets OP's requirements.